# Oracle-Cloud Typescript SDK Object Storage File Upload content type

Tags: typescript, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

## Object Storage File Uploads

I am able to upload files using the Typescript SDK using my web browser and the cloud web app, as well as, the [typescript SDK](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/SDKDocs/typescriptsdk.htm). When a .css file is uploaded via the browser, it correctly has the `Content Type: text/css` however when I perform the upload via a script of the EXACT same file, the result is a `Content Type:application/octet-stream` and the file is of no use. I can't load it as CSS.

The code I am using is unmodified straight from the example. and it works perfectly, except for this issue. Im making sure to NOT do a multi part upload, and in fact the console prints out

```bash
    Calling operation ObjectStorageClient#putObject.
    Retry policy to use: MaximumNumberAttempts=undefined, MaxSleepBetween=30, ExponentialBackoffBase=2
    Total Latency for this API call is: 189 ms
    uploading using single upload
```

Which seems like it should not be "streaming" the file and instead doing a simple PUT.

**PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE** if anyone can help me. I really am liking oracle's cloud stuff and I want to get this to work.

```
const common = require("oci-common");
const os = require("oci-objectstorage");

// import { basename, join } from "path";
const { basename, join } = require("path");
// import { readdir } from "fs";
const { readdir } = require("fs");

const provider = new common.ConfigFileAuthenticationDetailsProvider();


const client = new os.ObjectStorageClient({ authenticationDetailsProvider: provider });

const uploadManager = new os.UploadManager(client, { enforceMD5: true });
const directoryPath = "./css" 
const namespaceName = "blahblah"
const bucketName = "example-012724"

(async () => {
  // Read files from the directory
  readdir(directoryPath, (err, files) => {
    if (err) return console.log("Unable to scan directory: " + err);

    files.forEach(async filename => {
      const objectName = `${basename(filename)}`;
      console.log(`Uploading ${objectName}`);

      try {
        console.time("Upload Time");
        const callback = res => {
          console.log("Progress: ", res);
        };
        await uploadManager.upload(
          {
            content: {
              filePath: join(directoryPath, filename)
            },
            requestDetails: {
              namespaceName: namespaceName,
              bucketName: bucketName,
              objectName: objectName
            }
          },
          callback
        );

        console.timeEnd("Upload Time");
      } catch (ex) {
        console.error(`Failed due to ${ex}`);
      }
    });
  });
})();
```

Comment: I am still trying to get this working, I have been reading about the S3 compatibility layer, where you can use an s3 library with oracle so if I cant figure it out, I might try that route...